# Expresión regular que solo acepte una cadena, con tres textos o textos con espacio, separados por comas

Tags: regex

Como hacer una expresion regular que solo acepte una cadena, con tres textos o textos con espacio, separados por comas.

Por ejemplo:

```
Trujillo, La Libertad, Sipan o Lima, Lima, Villa el salvador
```

Intente este:

```
^[a-zA-Z ]+(,[a-zA-Z ]+)*$
```

pero cuando pongo solo una palabra me lo acepta y no quiero eso, ya que deseo que sea tres palabras o frases separadas por comas.

Comment: Intente este ^[a-zA-Z ]+(,[a-zA-Z ]+)*$ pero cuando pongo solo una palabra me lo acepta y no quiero eso, ya que deseo que sea tres palabras o frases separadas por comas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo la **REGEX** que va a permitir 3 textos alfanuméricos separados por coma evitando los textos vacios :

```
(( )*[a-zA-Z1-9]+( )*)+,(( )*[a-zA-Z1-9]+( )*)+,(( )*[a-zA-Z1-9]+( )*)+
```

- Con esta herramienta vas a poder validar las Expresiones que vayas armando y hacer diferentes pruebas: https://regexr.com/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Espero que te sea de utilidad.

**Saludos atte! :)**

Comment: Muchas gracias :) hay alguna forma que exija que se escriba el tercer texto, ya que la expresion me acepta hasta "text1, tex2, " y quisiera que haya texto en esa ultima parte.

Comment: @LuisLaraAriza 
Fijate que hice unos cambios de la *REGEX* para que te permita ingresar números y no te permita que el texto sea solo espacio (Debe incluir al menos 1 caracter alfanumérico).

Si te fue de ayuda no olvides de votar positivo!
Saludos y estoy a tu disposición :)